# Webpack: make sass-loader `additionalData` dependent on the entry name

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader, theming

I have a react application, whose components import sass files for styling. I am bundling everything with webpack and I would like to generate different css for different themes.

In my webpack config I defined two entries

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        "theme1": {
            import: ["./src/index.js?theme1"],
        },
        "theme2": {
            import: ["./src/index.js?theme2"],
        },
    },
```

The sass-loader should prepend themes variables to sass files depending on the entry name:

```
loader: "sass-loader",
    options: {
        additionalData: (content, loaderContext) => {
             if (CURRENT_ENTRY == 'theme1') return "@use 'theme1.scss' as vars";
             else return "@use 'theme2.scss' as vars";

        },
    }
```

But I can't get the current entry... any idea if this is possible or any suggestions for alternative solutions?

Comment: I ended up using env variables and launching the webpack compilation for each theme separately

Answer (score -2):

You can check it in `loaderContext.resourceQuery`.